# Obtener el ultimo elemento de un array javascript

Tags: javascript, array, google-maps

quiero obtener el ultimo elemento de un array que obtiene datos de una consulta a mysql, ocupo el ultimo elemento para pasarlo a un string y despues pasarle ese dato (que son unas cordenadas) a un fragmento de mapa de google maps, mi pregunta es para saber como hacer lo del array y que recomiendan para lo de google, no tengo mucha experiencia en este de ajax y js, ya probe varias cosas para lo del arreglo, porque encontre que con un array.length me podia funcionar, pero no, o talvez lo estoy haciendo mal. Aqui les dejo mi codigo.

```
function Cargar() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "consulta.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
 var array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 var i;
 var out = "<table border='1'>";



    **EL ARRAY QUE QUIERO OBTENER ->** var titulo = array[a].descripcion
    var a = array.lenght
    document.write(titulo);





 out += "</table>";
 document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = out;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: Ignoren la estructura incompleta de la tabla

Comment: Has probado con `array[array.length - 1].descripcion`?

Comment: Me funciono muy bien, gracias :))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
array[array.length - 1].descripcion
```

debe funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Lo que comenta Evgeni es totalmente correcto, y probablemente la manera en que todos lo haciamos, pero ahora (2022) a salido un nuevo metodo muy interesante y facil de usar que lo hace mas fluido - Method ***.at()***

Asi que podrias hacer esto directamente:

```
array.at(-1)
```

***-- EXPLICACION MAS A FONDO --***

`at()` se introdujo el método en *ECMAScript 2022.*

Supongamos que tenemos una array ordenada en orden ascendente. Queremos obtener el mayor número en la matriz ordenada.

```
const sortedArray = [4, 10, 30, 100, 202, 400];
```

(Antes)
Una forma de obtener el ultimo numero es accediendo a la array.lengthpropiedad.

```
 console.log(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1]); //400
```

Del mismo modo, podemos obtener el 'N' elemento más grande como se muestra a continuación:

```
console.log(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - N]);
```

El uso de este método agrega algunos inconvenientes:

Necesitamos almacenar la array en una variable.
Necesitamos usar el nombre de la array repetidamente
Es hostil a los valores anónimos.
Si el nombre de la array es grande, la sintaxis afecta la legibilidad.

La otra forma es usar `array.slice`

`.slice()` ya admite índices negativos, por lo que coincide con nuestro requisito.

**Greatest element**

```
console.log(sortedArray.slice(-1)[0]); //400
```

**To get the 'N'th element.**

```
 console.log(sortedArray.slice(-N)[0]);
```

Este método evita algunos de los inconvenientes de usar *length*:

Evita la repetición de nombres.
Amigable con los valores anónimos.
Sin embargo, la sintaxis de uso a*rray.slice* es un poco rara, especialmente ***[0]***.

Después
ECMAScript 2022 agrega `at()` un método en Array, String y TypedArray.

Sintaxis

```
en(índice);

Parámetro : índice
```

El índice del elemento de la array al que se debe acceder. El parámetro *'índice'* admite la indexación relativa desde el final de la array cuando se pasa un índice negativo.

Valor devuelto :

El elemento de la array que coincide con el índice dado. Vuelve undef.. y no se encuentra el índice.

**Largest element in array**

```
console.log(sortedArray.at(-1)); //400
```

**'N'th largest element.**

```
console.log(sortedArray.at(-N));
```

**Undefined when index not found**

console.log(sortedArray.at(100)); //undefined

**Works with string**

```
"Saeloun".at(-1); //n
```

Comment: Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/543367/edit) la respuesta y ponle los formatos correctos para que se entienda donde empieza y donde acaba el código.

Comment: Excelente explicación!